# How can I make sibling elements take on the width of the largest sibling?

Tags: html, css

I have 2-3 `li` inside of a `ul`. The `ul` has a set width. The text in the `li` tags will vary but we want to maintain a minimum width of 100px for each of them. For `li` with more text we want to ensure that there is 15 pixels of padding on their left and right.

Ideally, all of the `li` would be identical in width i.e. they would all take on the width of the largest `li`. `min-width:100px` ensures that all of the `li` will be the same width when they are all below 100 pixels, but if one is above this width, the others must scale up to match.

Can I achieve this using only css/html? I believe I can solve this somewhat easily with javascript but I'd like to solve it without it.

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/a8ho4b04/3/

html:

```
<ul>
  <li class="li-1">--- --------</li>
  <li class="li-2">------- ------ ------</li>
  <li class="li-3">---</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul {
  display: block;
  width: 450px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.li-1 {
  background-color: green;
}
.li-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.li-3 {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Flexbox**

```css
ul {
  width: 450px;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
}
li {
  flex: 1;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.li-1 {
  background-color: green;
}
.li-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.li-3 {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li-1">--- --------</li>
  <li class="li-2">------- ------ ------</li>
  <li class="li-3">---</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS Tables**

```css
ul {
  width: 450px;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  display: table-cell;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
.li-1 {
  background-color: green;
}
.li-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
.li-3 {
  background-color: cyan;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="li-1">--- --------</li>
  <li class="li-2">------- ------ ------</li>
  <li class="li-3">---</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can give them a fixed width (in pixels), or a minimum width (which can be relative).